# How do I delete lines from a file 'in-place' without creating a temporary file?

Tags: python, algorithm, file, memory

I wrote 3 separate test cases for a program that I was writing. Unfortunately I filled up my hard drive doing so, maybe about 300+ gbs. I'd like to take samples from each test case file, and delete the rest of the file.

I know how to read lines in place without consuming memory using 'readline', so I can take one line from each file and put it in a new file, then make the file index point to the next line instead of the first line, thereby freeing up storage space.

Is this possible using python libraries?

Edit: took `sed` out, it creates a temp file

Comment: So you already know how to get individual lines, and you just want to write them to a new file, or are you also wanting to rewrite the original file without that first line?

Comment: I'm trying to rewrite the original file in place, without having to copy the lines that I'm not currently working on to memory.

Comment: _then make the file index point to the next line_ how do you do that? Are you working on windows or linux?

Comment: Ok `sed` did not do it in place, it threw a "no space left" error

Comment: `sed` will rewrite the entire file. You kinda have to in most cases because files are block oriented, they aren't really addressable line at a time. There is likely some way to fiddle with inodes or something, but copying is usually the right way to go.

Comment: @tdelaney that's a good point about blocks, is there a way to do an entire block then?

Comment: How big is the sample relative to the original file that you can't do a sample and then delete the original?

Comment: @JonClements I was thinking half of each original file.

Comment: @JFA okay and you either 1) can't re-run and sample your output as you go or 2) don't have resources to do a file at a time with space left, or 3) can't create a view of the file (means your existing file is still there) but you can effectively read a sample of it? Also does it have to be a random sample or could you for instance just truncate the existing files?

Comment: Say largest file is no. 3: copy file no. 3 to another machine, delete said file, reduce the size of files no. 1 and no.2, copy back no.3 and reduce its size too. Don't forget to clean up the other machine... You have access to another machine, haven't you?

Comment: You want to sample + delete from the original file while writing the new one? That's doable on linux... mostly... but since file systems tend to be journaled you usually don't get rid of the data immediately and may have problems still.

Comment: You could also gzip the files if you don't mind trading increased time to read verses disk size.

Comment: @JonClements in the worst case scenario I'd rerun the original scripts to produce those files, which took quite a bit of time, in the second to worst case, I'd offload all the files to a larger hard drive, at SATA, USB, or network speeds, then combine them, and then bring them back to my computer.

Comment: @tdelaney the issue is that my drive was full. I had a similar memory limitation issue which lead me to learn how to use techniques that preserved memory space. I thought I'd take this opportunity to learn to see if there are disk saving techniques, but it sounds like it's going to take a little more effort. I'll just run that one at a different time.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to take samples from each test case file, and delete the rest of the file.

Read line by line from the top. Write pieces you want to keep into the beginning of the file. Keep the current offset where the samples end in the file and where the unread part begins.

If the copied piece may overlap with the destination; use the algorithm similar to [`memmove(fp+current_offset, fp+unread_offset, count)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memmove): *"copy bytes forwards from the beginning of the buffer"*. After the copy:

```
current_offset += count
unread_offset += count
```

Continue until enough samples are taken, then call `file.truncate(current_offset)` to remove everything after the samples in the file.

For example, if you want to keep half of the lines at random:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random

with open('big-big.file', 'r+b') as file:
    current_offset = file.tell()
    while True:
        line = file.readline() # b'\n'-separated lines
        if not line: # EOF
            break
        if random.random() < 0.5: # keep the line
            unread_offset = file.tell()
            file.seek(current_offset)
            file.write(line)
            current_offset = file.tell()
            file.seek(unread_offset)
    file.truncate(current_offset)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt to rewrite the files in place with `mmap`. I don't want to fill my hard drive so didn't test anything large. Its a runnable example but you'll want to gut the stuff at the front and back that I used for testing.

This writes the first 50% of the file to a new file then trims it. Not sure if that's the order you wanted it in!

```
import mmap

import shutil
import os
from glob import glob

files_to_trim = 'deleteme*'
fraction_to_keep = .5
blocksize = 128*1024

# make test file
open('deleteme1', 'w').writelines('all work and no play {}\n'.format(i)
    for i in range(6))
open('deleteme2', 'w').writelines('all work and no play {}\n'.format(i)
    for i in range(10,18))


with open('output', 'wb') as out:
    for filename in sorted(glob(files_to_trim)):
        st_size = os.stat(filename).st_size
        sample_size = int(st_size * fraction_to_keep)
        with open(filename, 'r+b') as infile:
            memfile = mmap.mmap(infile.fileno(), 0)
            # find next line ending
            need_newline = False
            count = memfile.find(b'\n', sample_size)
            if count >= 0:
                count += 1 # account for \n
            else:
                count = st_size
                need_newline = memfile[-1] == '\n'
            # copy blocks to outfile
            for rpos in range(0, count+blocksize-1, blocksize):
                out.write(memfile[rpos:min(rpos+blocksize, count)])
            if need_newline:
                out.write('\n')
            # trim infile
            remaining = st_size - count
            memfile[:remaining] = memfile[count:]
            memfile.flush()
            memfile.close()
            infile.truncate(remaining)
            infile.flush()

# validate test file
print('deleteme1:')
print(open('deleteme1').read())
print('deleteme2:')
print(open('deleteme2').read())
print('output:')
print(open('output').read())
```

Comment: Ok, I can give you my test case generators if you change your mind about filling your hard drive.

Comment: ...or you can check whether your stuff is blown to pieces! - smile